# Fetching data and display it as a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

I'm working with a Grafana plugin API and I'm trying to create a function that returns an object literal `var literals` that will contain new data that I fetched from the server.
The result of this function `return literals;` will go, as a parameter, in to another Grafana API function later.
I'm very confused by how promises work and I don't really know how to tackle this problem.

Right now in this code I'm having a problem with a console error

> TypeError: data.dbs is undefined'

at the line `data.dbs.forEach(element => {`

I thought that after calling the `.then()` function the data should already be returned and yet it's still unresolved?

I would also like to know how exactly can I create this whole `getDropdown()` function so that it will be able to send the resolved data forward?

```js
export function getDropdown() {
  var literals = {
    path: 'displayMode',
    name: 'Cell display mode',
    description: 'Color text, background, show as gauge, etc',
    settings: {
      options: [{
        value: 1,
        label: 'Placeholder'
      }],
    },
  };

  var data = {
    dbs: [{
      id: 1,
      database: 'placeholder',
    }, ],
  };


  fetch('/api/datasources')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(json => {

      data = json;
      var counter = 0;
      data.dbs.forEach(element => {
        literals.settings.options[counter].label = element.database;
        literals.settings.options[counter].value = element.id;
        counter++;
      });


    });

  return literals;
}
```

I was able to solve the problem with this code

```
fetch('/api/datasources')
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach((element: { database: string; id: number }) => {
        literals.settings.options[counter].label = element.database;
        literals.settings.options[counter].value = element.id;
        counter++;
      });
    });
```

I think there was something wrong with `data.dbs` but I'm still not sure what.

Comment: Can you console.log(json) and see what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using then() functions, try using async/await where you can asyncronously execute functions & you can also wait till getting a promise.

In the above code you can write an async function & await till you get response from
**fetch('/api/datasources')**

```js
// Do
async function getData() {
  var data = await fetch('/api/datasources')
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
  jsonData.dbs.forEach(element => {
    literals.settings.options[counter].label = element.database;
    literals.settings.options[counter].value = element.id;
    counter++;
  });
}

// Instead of
fetch('/api/datasources')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(json => {

      data = json;
      var counter = 0;
      data.dbs.forEach(element => {
        literals.settings.options[counter].label = element.database;
        literals.settings.options[counter].value = element.id;
        counter++;
      });


    });
```